# Run npm commandes on cpanel directly

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, command-line, cpanel

I just **upload** script (**laravel** + **vue.js**) to CPanel , and every thing works fine,
but i need to make some changes in vue js components.
my question is there any method to run npm commandes directly on cpanel?

```
npm run dev
npm run watch
```

i already saw some examples about **ssh** login key but no solution.

Comment: Normally you execute `npm run prod` on your local machine and push this code to the server. You should never run these commands on the server directly

Comment: yes right , but if there any modificatio thene i should return to my project on  local and do modifications after that push code again , imean no other solution ?

Comment: Yes, because otherwise you will  probably get merge errors and it will cause some downtime. But if you really wan't to do it you will have to login via termial SSH

Comment: yes i have ssh and itry to connect it with cmd but hi didn't give me directory they show public_html and some dir but empty

Answer (score 0):

i should return to my project on local and do modifications after that push code again

Answer (score 0):

In Cpanel I found the terminal,
I open it and cd to the laravel project path and run any npm or artisan command,